# C# audio output without a stream or buffer

Tags: c#, windows, audio, speaker

I'm working on a program that I want to have some audio output. I would use System.Media.SoundPlayer, except that the data is generated dynamically and in real time. I really just want to set the speaker to a single byte value, and change that value when needed. Any buffers or streams would make this overly complicated.

Comment: You need buffers even at lowest level, since on audio hardware would allow you to send one sample at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  `System.Media.SoundPlayer` works on streams, either dynamically generated like you want or generated from a file.

Learn to work with streams.  They're not complicated.  Certainly less complicated then dynamically generating audio.

Comment: It's very little complication to have `Read()` overridden and return ONE sample at a time, and have `SoundPlayer` output it.

Comment: @DanielMošmondor, one sample yes, but not one byte as the OP asked.  `SoundPlayer` requires valid wav data and validates the header thoroughly.

Comment: Op will have to learn that audio granularity is one sample and not one byte.  And wav header could easily be faked :)